# How could I do this indentation?

Tags: indentation

What code could I use for making the indentation in the image below?

[image: Example of indentation]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you want this for your normal text or for you bibliography like in the picture? If it is the latter we need to know how you produce you bibliography now (`biblatex`, `natbib`, …) with the help of an example document

Comment: And for normal tex not bibliography itemize should do it.

Comment: Yes i want the indentation for normal text, but itemize don't do that...i am working in the class "article"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the `hanging` package to achieve your objective. The first argument of the `hangparas` environment controls the amount of indentation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text
\begin{document}
\begin{hangparas}{2em}{1}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{hangparas}
\end{document}
```